# How to resize d3js charts on resizing of ui-portlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created one simple chart from d3js library example but when i am using that chart in portlet and when i am resizing portlet chart doesnt resize. it remain in default size.

Below is my example:
D3js Code:

```
 var m = [30, 50, 10, 30],
    w = 600 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 400 - m[0] - m[2];

    var format = d3.format(",.0f");

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .1);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-h),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

      var svg = d3.select(".portlet-content").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
       .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
     .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
       .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400")
       .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);

  // Parse numbers, and sort by value.
  data.forEach(function(d) { d.value = +d.value; });
  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  // Set the scale domain.
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

  var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.name) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("class", "value")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
      .attr("dx", 50)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

html code:

```
<div class="portlet">
<div class="portlet-header">Header</div>
<div class="portlet-content">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I usually make an on window resize function that calls the window width/height to make the chart responsive.

Comment: i am using jquery ui portlet to show charts, so when i am resizing portlet chart is not resizing.

Comment: i am not sure i understand. can't you change the size of the charts (the h and w vars) on resize, then view in the portlet?